# android Loading Kernel using openCL 2.0 with cl2.hpp

Tags: android, c++, opencl

I wanted to jump to openCL 200 has my ARM G72 support it.
But i found out that there is big difference between cl.hpp (old openCL ;))) and cl2.hpp.

Before i used to load my kernel :

```
    int src_length = 0;
    const char* src  = file_contents("/data/data/com.example/app_execdir/kernels.cl",&src_length);
    cl::Program::Sources sources(1,std::make_pair(src, src_length) );
    program = cl::Program(gContext, sources);
    program.build(devices,NULL,cb);
    while(program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS>(devices[0]) != CL_BUILD_SUCCESS);
    gCompression        = cl::Kernel(program, "compression", &err);
```

But when i compile my cpp using cl2.hpp with all the new #define. I got plenty of error message using CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 200

```
error: 'CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_ON_HOST_PROPERTIES' was not declared
note: in definition of macro 'CL_HPP_DECLARE_PARAM_TRAITS_'
note: in expansion of macro 'CL_HPP_PARAM_NAME_INFO_2_0_'
```

when i use CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120 i get only 1 compile error ;)) but this one concern the kernel compilation. the cl::Program::Sources sources(1,std::make_pair(src, src_length) ); here is my log :

```
C:/Users/user/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/androidcl-master/app/src/main/jni/processor.cpp:564:72: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::vector(int, std::pair<const char*, int>)'
         cl::Program::Sources sources(1,std::make_pair(src, src_length) );
                                                                        ^
C:/Users/user/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/androidcl-master/app/src/main/jni/processor.cpp:564:72: note: candidates are:
In file included from C:/android-ndk-r12b/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/vector:64:0,
                 from C:/android-ndk-r12b/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/random.h:34,
                 from C:/android-ndk-r12b/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/random:49,
                 from C:/android-ndk-r12b/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
                 from C:/android-ndk-r12b/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/algorithm:62,
                 from C:/Users/user/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/androidcl-master/app/src/main/jni/processor.cpp:23:
C:/android-ndk-r12b/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/stl_vector.h:445:9: note: template<class _InputIterator, class> std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const allocator_type&)
         vector(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
         ^
C:/android-ndk-r12b/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/stl_vector.h:445:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/Users/user/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/androidcl-master/app/src/main/jni/processor.cpp:564:72: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter '_InputIterator' ('int' and 'std::pair<const char*, int>')
         cl::Program::Sources sources(1,std::make_pair(src, src_length) );
```

I really does not anderstand what is the problem. I am not so good in C and C++ anymore. To much change those last 25 years ;))

Answer (score 0):

for the error using CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120 we must add

```
#define CL_HPP_ENABLE_PROGRAM_CONSTRUCTION_FROM_ARRAY_COMPATIBILITY
```

for the error using CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 200

```
#define CL_HPP_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#define CL_EXT_PREFIX__VERSION_1_1_DEPRECATED
#define CL_EXT_PREFIX__VERSION_1_2_DEPRECATED
#define CL_API_SUFFIX__VERSION_2_0
#define CL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION 110 
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 200 
#define CL_HPP_ENABLE_PROGRAM_CONSTRUCTION_FROM_ARRAY_COMPATIBILITY
#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 200
```

One error is also if you have many version of include/CL if to not forget that the file must be in CL directorie and not CLx CLy. Because all include relate to CL directorie. ;))